# Android Wear Prevent Sleep

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm writing a small wear app that is required to be quick access for around 10 - 15 minutes at a time. Problem is when the watch sleeps (screen completely blacks out) you have to go back into the start app screen to get back to it.

The data is retained so this is more of an annoying than anything else. Is there anyway to have the watch only dim the screen but not turn it "off" until the user dismisses the app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please take a look at a session from Google I/O 2014: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sha_w3_5c2c#t=1241 <- 20:42

Justin talks there about `android:keepScreenOn="true"` attribute to prevent the timeout and "back to homescreen" behavior.

Please read more info about keeping screen on here: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen

Comment: Perfect. I had been using `KeepScreenOn` just not in the right place.