# Customizing Android Wear watch timeout programmatically

Tags: android, wear-os

I would like to allow the users of my Android Wear app to customize the timeout length of the backlight for my watch face. I've found an [app that is able to do so](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonephreak.extendedlight&hl=en), but I am unable to figure out how it does it. Has anyone been able to adjust screen timeout on an android wear device?

Comment: I don't believe this is offtopic. I'm asking how to accomplish something that is possible using the Android Wear SDK I just do not know how to do so, and it is not obvious from reading the documentation.

Comment: maybe one of these helps ;) https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screenhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035523/android-wear-prevent-sleep

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035523/android-wear-prevent-sleep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to listen to screen state event in a persistent service.
You can achieve that [with this code](https://gist.github.com/PomepuyN/cdd821eca163a3279de2).
Then, when the screen is in `STATE_ON` state, just acquire a wakelock and release it after the determined time. You can find how to do it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen).

Please keep in mind that it will have a negative effect on the battery life, especially on Wear devices that have small batteries.

Comment: What are "on ear" devices with Android Wear?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I fixed it (on Wear devices).

Comment: Normally the device turns its display off `n` seconds after the user last touched the screen, not `n` seconds after the display was turned on.